# Python decorator that returns a function with one or more arguments replaced

Tags: python, decorator, partial, python-decorators

I would like to create a decorator to a set of functions that replaces one or more of the arguments of the functions. The first thought that came to my mind was to create a decorator that returns a partial of the function with the replaced arguments.
I'm unhappy with the way the decorated function is called, but even when it's being called "properly", i get a TypeError.

Here is some example code:

```
def decor(func, *args, **kwargs):
    def _new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return partial(func, *args, **kwargs, v=100)
    return _new_func

@decor
def some_function(a, v, c):
    return a, v, c

some_function(1,2,3)  # functools.partial(<function some_function at 0x7f89a8bed8c8>, 1, 2, 3, v=100)
some_function(1,2,3)(1,2,3)  # TypeError: some_function() got multiple values for argument 'v'
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to create a decorator that replaces some of the arguments, but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to return the partial as the decoration result:

```
def decor(func):
    return partial(func, v=100)
```

However, this *always* sets `v=100`, even if you passed in another value for `v` by position. You'd still have the same issue.

You'd need to create a decorator that knows what positional argument `v` is, and look for it there *and* as a keyword argument:

```
from inspect import getargspec

def decor(func):
    vpos = getargspec(func).args.index('v')
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > vpos:
            args = list(args)
            args[vpos] = 100
        else:
            kwargs['v'] = 100
        return func(*args, **kwargs)        
    return wrapper
```

The above decorator will set the `v` argument to 100, *always*. Wether you tried to set `v` as a positional argument or as a keyword argument, in the end it'll be set to 100 anyway:

```
>>> @decor
... def some_function(a, v, c):
...     return a, v, c
...
>>> some_function(1, 2, 3)
(1, 100, 3)
>>> some_function(1, v=2, c=3)
(1, 100, 3)
```

If you only wanted to provide a default argument for `v` if it wasn't explicitly set, you'd have to invert the tests:

```
def decor(func):
    vpos = getargspec(func).args.index('v')
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) <= vpos and 'v' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['v'] = 100
        return func(*args, **kwargs)        
    return wrapper
```

at which point `v` is only provided if not already set:

```
>>> @decor
... def some_function(a, v, c):
...     return a, v, c
...
>>> some_function(1, c=3)  # v not set
(1, 100, 3)
>>> some_function(1, 2, c=3)  # v is set
(1, 2, 3)
>>> some_function(1, v=2, c=3)  # v is set as keyword argument
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this elaborated answer!

Comment: Nice answer (as always!), but using the variable name `argv` here is... misleading.  Isn't there another name you could choose?

Comment: @alexis: the argument with the name `v`... ;-) I'll think of a better one.