# Python - Using decorated function's argument values in the decorator using named arguments

Tags: python, arguments, decorator

In continue to: [Python decorator that returns a function with one or more arguments replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061956/python-decorator-that-returns-a-function-with-one-or-more-arguments-replaced/40061972#40061972)

I would like to use the values of arguments passed by users in the decorator itself using the argument names. Is it even possible? if it does, how can it be done?

An exmaple:

Let's say my decorator manipulates a simple function, something like:

```
def f(a, b, c): 
    pass
```

and my decorator manipulates the value of `b` that is being passed to the function.

Here is my decorator:

```
def decorate(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('in wrapper', args, kwargs)
        kwargs['b'] = kwargs['b'] * 5
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Let's assume that i know there should b a 'b' in the function, but i'm not sure regarding its position.

I hope that now it's clear. Thanks!

Comment: The wrapper function *necessarily* receives all parameters that will be passed to the function it wraps, so: yes, of course. How have you *tried* to do it, and what precisely went wrong?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what values you're trying to pass?

Comment: I added an example in my question

Comment: ...so where is the example of the decorator you're applying? Have you read any of the many resources on writing Python decorators on SO and elsewhere? This is much too broad a question in the general case, and just an exercise in writing your code for you in a very specific case.

Comment: You are right, i'll rephrase it. Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe - i rephrased my question, hope it's clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Not really. What's the *problem* with what you've written?